# Выбор окончания в слове

Tags: выбор-слов

В справочнике указаны номера телефонов производителей кассовой машины, где можно получить консультацию по каждой модели, а также номер телефона Центра техуслуг, который занимается выбранной вами модели.

Comment: Какое слово-то? Если "занимается" (чем?), то ***"моделью"*** А если "производителей" (чего?), то, вероятно, все-таки ***"кассовых машин"***.

Comment: Либо «телефонов, по которым», либо «производителей, у которых». Разговорное «где» не комильфо.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы оформила это предложение так:

*В справочнике указаны номера телефонов производителей кассовой машины (**по ним** можно получить консультацию по каждой модели), а также номер телефона **центра** техуслуг, который занимается **обслуживанием и ремонтом** выбранной вами модели.*

Слово "центр" необходимо писать со строчной буквы, так как словосочетание *центр техуслуг* не является названием (именем собственным).
Сравните: центр медуслуг, центр занятости, сервисный центр.

Занимается (чем?) обслуживанием (чего?) модели.